# Passing source file name to destination in an ADFv1 pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-storage, etl, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

### Scenario

I'm developing an ETL with Azure Data Factory v1 (unfortunately **I can't use Azure Data Factory v2**).

I want to read all .csv files from a given blob storage container, then write the content of each file to a table in SQL Azure.

### The problem

The destination table contains all the columns from the csv file. It must also contain a new column with the name of the file where the data come from.

This is where I'm stuck: I can't find a way to pass the file name from the source dataset (.csv file from blob storage source) to the destination dataset (Sql Azure sink).

### What I have already tried

I already implemented a pipeline that reads a file from blob storage and saves it to a table in SQL Azure.

Here is an excerpt from the json that copies a single file to SQL Azure:

```js
{
    "name": "pipelineFileImport",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BlobSource",
                        "recursive": false
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlSink",
                        "writeBatchSize": 0,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "00:00:00"
                    },
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "columnMappings": "TypeOfRecord:TypeOfRecord,TPMType:TPMType,..."
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "InputDataset-cn0"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "OutputDataset-cn0"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "1.00:00:00",
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst",
                    "style": "StartOfInterval",
                    "retry": 3,
                    "longRetry": 0,
                    "longRetryInterval": "00:00:00"
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Day",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "name": "Activity-0-pipelineFileImport_csv->[staging]_[Files]"
            }
        ],
        "start": "2018-07-20T09:50:55.486Z",
        "end": "2018-07-20T09:50:55.486Z",
        "isPaused": false,
        "hubName": "test_hub",
        "pipelineMode": "OneTime",
        "expirationTime": "3.00:00:00",
        "datasets": [
            {
                "name": "InputDataset-cn0",
                "properties": {
                    "structure": [
                        {
                            "name": "TypeOfRecord",
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "TPMType",
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        ...
                    ],
                    "published": false,
                    "type": "AzureBlob",
                    "linkedServiceName": "Source-TestBlobStorage",
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "fileName": "testFile001.csv",
                        "folderPath": "fileinput",
                        "format": {
                            "type": "TextFormat",
                            "columnDelimiter": ";",
                            "firstRowAsHeader": true
                        }
                    },
                    "availability": {
                        "frequency": "Day",
                        "interval": 1
                    },
                    "external": true,
                    "policy": {}
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "OutputDataset-cn0",
                "properties": {
                    "structure": [
                        {
                            "name": "TypeOfRecord",
                            "type": "String"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "TPMType",
                            "type": "String"
                        },...
                    ],
                    "published": false,
                    "type": "AzureSqlTable",
                    "linkedServiceName": "Destination-SQLAzure-cn0",
                    "typeProperties": {
                        "tableName": "[staging].[Files]"
                    },
                    "availability": {
                        "frequency": "Day",
                        "interval": 1
                    },
                    "external": false,
                    "policy": {}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### What I need

I need a way to pass the name of the source file to the destination dataset in order to write it in the SQL Azure database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No native way to handle this. But I think you could use a stored procedure to achieve this.

Please reference for stored procedure property.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-azure-sql-connector#copy-activity-properties

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using a stored procedure is probably a good solution, but I would still need to pass the current filename to the stored procedure and this takes me back to the core of my question: how to pass the filename to the dataset/stored procedure

Comment: With ADF v2, you could use get metadata activity to get the file name. In v1, maybe you could consider the .net custom activity.